# что почитать о решениях нечётких множеств?

Tags: математика, разработка-игр, теория

Хочется написать бот для игры в rummy / кун-кен

На сколько я понимаю логика получается нечёткая.
Дерево решений? мне кажется будет очень большое.
Коллапс волновой функции применить?
Нейронные сети в конце концов, хоть и не совсем подходят мне кажется.

Наверняка кто-то делал подобное. Может встречались вам разборы?

Comment: Скажите, а почему Вы думаете, что стандартный минимакс не даст Вам достаточно хорошего алгоритма? Ведь, как я понял правила игры, там есть вполне четкий подсчет очков, прямо как и надо для минимакса? Хотя, вполне возможно, я просто не понимаю сложности задачи, которую решает бот.

Comment: Нечеткая логика хорошо применима для задач типа "погоня собаки за кошкой" когда догоняющий отлавливает отклонения и их скорость. Не уверен что этот алгоритм применим для вашего случая.
Нейронная сеть это по сути многомерный классификатор, преимущество которого в самообучении, кода не надо прописывать все решения руками. Фактически это что-то вроде "собаки Павлова". Но для самообучения нужны достоверные фактографические данные ходов участников игры и их результаты.

Comment: Тоже кручу в голове подход минимакса. К своему стыду не знал этого термина. Спасибо. Фактически велик изобрёл уже :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Круглов - Нечёткая логика и искусственные нейронные сети
- McNeill - Fuzzy logic. A practical approach
- Zadeh - Fuzzy sets
- Батыршин - Основные операции нечеткой логики и их обобщения
- Вятченин - Нечеткие методы автоматической классификации
- Григорьев - Обработка ненадежных знаний в CLIPS
- Дюбуа Прад - Теория возможностей. Приложения к представлению знаний в информатике
- Заде - Понятие лингвистической переменной и его применение к принятию приближенных решений
- Заде - Тени нечетких множеств
- Заде - Принятие решений в расплывчатых условиях
- Кофман - Введение в теорию нечетких множеств
- Леоненков - Нечеткое моделирование в среде Matlab и FuzzyTech
- Поспелов - Нечеткие множества в моделях управления и искусственном интеллекте
- Тэрано - Прикладные нечеткие системы
- Яхъяева - Нечеткие множества и нейронные сети